# SUMIFS with OR criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

- I want to be able to use SUMIFS function with OR condition
- I have only one cell to work with, or display the result
- In the attached screen shot, I want to display the relevant score after entering the Type and Sub Type from a drop down Menu
- The tricky part is that the drop down menu also contains an item called "All" which when selected shows results for all the items irrespective of Type/Subtype
- For Example if I select Type as A, and Subtype as All, The Score should show me sum of all scores with all items of type A, irrespective of its subtype
- Similarly if I select SubType as X, and Type as All, The Score should show me sum of all scores with all items of Subtype A, irrespective of its Type
- Obviously if I select both a type(A,B,C) and a subtype(X,Y,Z), the score will show the sum of All items of that type and subtype.

Hope I have made my question clear.

Any help in this would be highly appreciated

[Excel Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5bj4.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5bj4.png]

Answer (score 1):

`*` =ALL

This formula wil work : `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,IF($G$3="All","*",$G$3),$B$2:$B$7,IF($H$3="All","*",$H$3))`

[image]